# App is not compatible with Nexsus 7

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

Hi i have an issue with Nexsus 7 tablet. I cannot find my app on play store using nexsus 7.When I go through browser link it says app is not compatible with this device.

Here is my Manifest file :

Below is the permission set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

and here is the compatibility screen tag :

```
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume it's something to do with:

1. Not providing a tablet layout
   and
2. For your app to be showcased in the 'Designed for tablets' list in the Play Store, you need to upload at least one 7- inch and one 10 - inch screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
```

The Nexus 7 has an unusual tvdpi density.